# cvHaarDetectObjects Memory Leak

Tags: opencv, memory-leaks, face-detection

I'm using the function cvHaarDetectObjects to do face detection and there is a memory leak checking with valgrind even though I think I freed all the memories. I really don't know how to fix the memory leak. Here is my code:

```
int Detect(MyImage* Img,MyImage **Face)
{

  Char* Cascade_name = new Char[1024];
  strcpy(Cascade_name,"/usr/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

    // Create memory for calculations
    CvMemStorage* Storage = 0;


    // Create a new Haar classifier
    CvHaarClassifierCascade* Cascade = 0;

    int Scale = 1;

    // Create two points to represent the face locations
    CvPoint pt1, pt2;
    int Loop;

    // Load the HaarClassifierCascade
    Cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( Cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );

    // Check whether the cascade has loaded successfully. Else report and error and quit
    if( !Cascade )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade\n" );
        exit(0);
    }

    // Allocate the memory storage
    Storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    // Clear the memory storage which was used before
    cvClearMemStorage( Storage );

    // Find whether the cascade is loaded, to find the faces. If yes, then:
    if( Cascade )
    {
        // There can be more than one face in an image. So create a growable sequence of faces.
        // Detect the objects and store them in the sequence

      CvSeq* Faces = cvHaarDetectObjects( Img->Image(), Cascade, Storage,
                                            1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                            cvSize(40, 40) );

        int MaxWidth = 0;
        int MaxHeight = 0;
        if(Faces->total == 0)
        {
           cout<<"There is no face."<<endl;
           return 1;
        }


       //just get the first face 
        for( Loop = 0; Loop <1; Loop++ )
        {
           // Create a new rectangle for drawing the face
            CvRect* Rect = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( Faces, Loop );

            // Find the dimensions of the face,and scale it if necessary
            pt1.x = Rect->x*Scale;
            pt2.x = (Rect->x+Rect->width)*Scale;
            if(Rect->width>MaxWidth) MaxWidth = Rect->width;
            pt1.y = Rect->y*Scale;
            pt2.y = (Rect->y+Rect->height)*Scale;
            if(Rect->height>MaxHeight) MaxHeight = Rect->height;
            cvSetImageROI( Img->Image(), *Rect );

            MyImage* Dest = new MyImage(cvGetSize(Img->Image()),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 

            cvCvtColor( Img->Image(), Dest->Image(), CV_RGB2GRAY );

            MyImage* Equalized = new MyImage(cvGetSize(Dest->Image()), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

            // Perform histogram equalization
            cvEqualizeHist( Dest->Image(), Equalized->Image());
            (*Face) = new MyImage(Equalized->Image());

            if(Equalized)
               delete Equalized;
            Equalized = NULL;

            if(Dest)
               delete Dest;
            Dest = NULL;

            cvResetImageROI(Img->Image());

        }

        if(Cascade)
        {
           cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &Cascade ); 
           delete Cascade;
           Cascade = NULL;
        }


        if(Storage)
        {
           cvClearMemStorage(Storage);

           cvReleaseMemStorage(&Storage);
           delete Storage;
           Storage = NULL;
        }
        if(Cascade_name)
           delete [] Cascade_name;
        Cascade_name = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

In the code, `MyImage` is a wrapper class of IplImage containing `IplImage* p` as a member. if the constructor takes a `IplImage* ppara` as parameter, then the member `p` will create memory using `cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(ppara), ppara->depth, ppara->nChannels)` and `cvCopy(ppara, p)`. if it takes size,depth and channels as parameter, then only do `cvCreateImage`. Then the destructor do `cvReleaseImage(&p)`. The function `int Detect(MyImage *Img, MyImage **Face)` is called like:

```
    IplImage *Temp = cvLoadImage(ImageName);

    MyImage* Img = new MyImage(Temp);
    if(Temp)
       cvReleaseImage(&Temp);
    Temp = NULL;     
    MyImage * Face = NULL;      
    Detect(Img, &Face);
```

I released Img and Face in the following code once the operations on them is done. And the memory leak is happened inside the Detect function. I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1 on 64 bit OS fedora 16. The whole program can terminate normally except for the memory leak.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why there is a memory leak. The reason is:

In the `MyImage` class constructor, I passed in a `IplImage* p` pointer, and do the following:

```
mp = cvCloneImage(p);
```

where `mp` is a `IplImage*` member of the `MyImage` class. I free the `IplImage*` pointer that I passed in after creating a new `MyImage` class object, since `cvCloneImage()` will create some memories. However I free the member pointer `mp` in the class destructor when it actually doesn't new any memory. It just points to memories that created by `cvCloneImage()`. So the memories created by `cvCloneImage()` isn't freed. This is where the memory leak came from.

Thus I do the following in the constructor given a `IplImage* p` passed in as parameter:

```
mp = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(p), p->depth, p->nChannels);
cvCopy(p, mp);
```

And free the `mp` pointer in the class destructor will free the memory that it creates.

After doing this, definitely lost and indirectly lost memories are turned to 0, but there are still possibly lost memories, and valgrind points all the lost record to the `cvHaarDetectObjects()` function which is from OpenCV. And mostly are caused by some "new threads" issues. Thus I googled this problem and found out `valgrind` does give possibly lost memories sometimes when new thread is involved. So I monitored the memory usage of the system. The result shows no memory usage building up as the program executed repeatedly.

That's what I found.